how to get every change of a TextField object?
I have exercise (picture 1)

It's study guide for windows forms app but I only have macOS with xamarin cocoa app.
I just don't know how I can get every change of a textField and do smth (in this case to assign this value to label)
I found a topic with the same problem here, but only pieces of code were provided there. I tried to insert them anywhere, but nothing works.
I couldn't ask anything either, it takes 50 reputations that I don't have.

    using System;
    
    using AppKit;
    using Foundation;
    
    namespace Application
    {
        public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
        {
            public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
            {
            }
    
            public override void ViewDidLoad ()
            {
                base.ViewDidLoad ();
                labelOnChange.StringValue = "";
    
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            }
    
            public override NSObject RepresentedObject {
                get {
                    return base.RepresentedObject;
                }
                set {
                    base.RepresentedObject = value;
                    // Update the view, if already loaded.
                }
            }
    
            private void textFieldOnChange_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NSNotification notification = sender as NSNotification;
            NSTextField textField = notification.Object as NSTextField;
            labelOnChange.StringValue = textField.StringValue;
        }
        }
    }



App's label doesn't change with field (on time when user input data)
I would appreciate it if you could explain how to do this step by step. I really want to understand every moment

Apart from this please don't post images of code, but instead copy your code directly into the question. Lats but not least: "my code doesn't work" is a really vague problem-description". Please be more specific on your problem, in particular about what you expect your code to do and what you get instead.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain what do you mean? We do this in C# language

Well, yes, however I have no idea which language #import <....h> refers to nor what @property is - definitly no C#.

@MakePeaceGreatAgain I don't print like "my code doesn't work". I ask "how to get every change of a TextField object?". What's wrong with you?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain dude, I don't ask how to add objects from Xcode builder to viewcontroller.h, I ask about how to work with this elements in vs

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

In line 32 you obviously already have a solution. So I think you just need to omit line 39. If this doens't solve the issue, please elaborate about the specific issue you get, not just "nothing works" (as mentioned in your question).

@MakePeaceGreatAgain check pls

Please do not post code as screenshots but as text. This is very hard to read.
You can subscribe to the Changed event of the NSTextField in the ViewDidLoad method:
labelOnChange.Changed += LabelChanged;

add that method LabelChanged to your viewcontroller:
void LabelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // get the new value
   string newValue = labelOnChange.StringValue;
}


`public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
base.ViewDidLoad ();
labelOnChange.Changed += LabelChanged;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }`

void LabelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)         {             // get the new value             string newValue = labelOnChange.StringValue;         }
and It still doesn't work

about code as screenshot
I'll take into account, thanks

DUUUUUUDE, I DID IT THANKS YOU
`public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
base.ViewDidLoad ();
textFieldOnChange.Changed += LabelChanged;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }`

void LabelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)         {             // get the new value             labelOnChange.StringValue = textFieldOnChange.StringValue;         }
